# Is it possible to define settimeout intervals in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, settimeout

Here's the situation:

```
var FireFlipTimer = '';
var UnFlipTimer = [];
$('.CategoryBox').on('mouseenter', '.Box', function() {
    clearTimeout(FireFlipTimer);
    var $t = $(this);
    var i = $t.index();
    clearTimeout(UnFlipTimer[i]);
    BHT = setTimeout(function() { FlipCat($t); }, 250);
}).on('mouseleave', '.Box', function() {
    clearTimeout(FireFlipTimer);
    var $t = $(this);
    var i = $t.index();
    UnFlipTimer[i] = setTimeout(function() { UnFlipCat($t); }, 600);
});
```

Basically there is a div, which on:

- mouseenter - animates
- mouseleave - after 600ms comes back to previous state before animation.

I'm trying to do thing, that if I leave the mouse and it enters the div in that 600ms interval, the div would not come back to previous state :)

As there are multiple div's I'm trying to handle setTimeout intervals with array, but not successfully...

Is it possible to define those intervals in array? Or should I use different method for this task.

P.S. The problem in this case is that only last element reacts to mouseleave event, if I go from div to div, previous divs are not comming back to normal state.

Comment: Have you tried the `$(...).stop(true)` function?

Comment: Your method should work (after correcting any errors that may be there). It may however be a little cleaner to store those timers in the respective elements itself using `.data()`. Also, naming your variables better will make your code way more readable. You can always minify them for production.

Comment: Got it, elements where not under same parent, so all had index = 0... Stupid me. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's becausethe `BHT` variable is just holding one timer (i.e. it is not an array of timers). And so the timer of the first element (as stored in the BHT variable) is overwritten by a next timer if you hover over multiple elements.

What you need to do is make the `BHT` variable an array, and use it just like the `BHT2` variable.

So it would look something like

```
var FireFlipTimer = [];
var UnFlipTimer = [];
$('.CategoryBox').on('mouseenter', '.Box', function() {
    var $t = $(this);
    var i = $t.index();
    clearTimeout(FireFlipTimer[i]);
    clearTimeout(UnFlipTimer[i]);
    FireFlipTimer[i] = setTimeout(function() { FlipCat($t); }, 250);
}).on('mouseleave', '.Box', function() {
    var $t = $(this);
    var i = $t.index();
    clearTimeout(FireFlipTimer[i]);
    UnFlipTimer[i] = setTimeout(function() { UnFlipCat($t); }, 600);
});
```

Comment: I edited the code to be more readable, so BHT or the FireFlipTimer fires animation on element if mouse entered and did not left div for 250ms. If it enters next div before the 250ms it does not Fires animation for last element, and starts new timer for the next element.

Comment: Noup, even with yours, the problem is If I enter one element, then I leave it and enter other one - the last one did not come back to previous state. They all do Fire animation, so It's not the case

Comment: Oh, sorry, the problem was with elements position, all those elements where not under same parent, so it's even work with mine solution. Anyway, thank you for the time & help Willem.